# Application stuck at File.OpenText()

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, json.net

in a Xamarin Android application I use this function to read data from a stored json-file

```
public async Task<Caselist> readData()
        {
            var file = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "data_covid_dashboard.json");
            try
            {
                System.Console.Write("Reading data...");
                using (StreamReader fileContent = File.OpenText(file))
                {
                    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(fileContent);
                    JObject jo = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                    return jo.ToObject<Caselist>();
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

However, the applications seems to be stuck on `using (StreamReader fileContent = File.OpenText(file))`

The desired file is about ~130MB.

Greetings,

Jonathan

Comment: If you're just going to convert to `Caselist` then you should skip loading it into a `JObject` first.  Try `var ser = new JsonSerializer();  return ser.Deserialize<Caselist>(reader);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Also thanks to Brian.

```
public async Task<Caselist> readData()
    {
        var file = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "data_covid_dashboard.json");
        try
        {
            System.Console.Write("Reading data...");
            using (StreamReader fileContent = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                var json = fileContent.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Caselist>(json);
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, remember to mark the answer when you have time, it will help others who have the same problems.